# Producing a git merge conflict

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm trying to produce a git merge conflict intentionally. Here is what I did

```
mkdir to-stack
cd to-stack
git init
vi a.txt
Added some text to first line of a.txt 
git add a.txt
git commit -m "Added a line to a.txt"

git checkout -b other
vi a.txt
Updated the text on first line of a.txt to something else
git add a.txt
git commit -m "Updated line 1"

git checkout master
git merge other
```

Merge happened and the content a.txt in master branch got overwritten to that of from other branch

I was expecting a Merge conflict to happen when doing the merge. Since I had changed the same line in other branch

Can you tell me why Merge conflict didn't happen in above case?

Comment: Why would that cause a problem? Version control isn't to make sure the same line isn't changed ever again. You're changing the line *after* the first change, which is just fine. You have to produce two separate changes with a common parent.

Answer (score 1):

A *merge* combines the changes from some common commit, to two *different* commits (whose relationship is that they both have that common commit in their histories).

That is, consider the following commit graph, where each `o` or `*` represents a commit, and every commit's *parent* is the commit that is found by following its connection leftwards (moving up or down if necessary):

```
          o   <-- branchA
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o   <-- branchB
```

The first commit that `branchA` and `branchB` *share* is the one marked `*`.  They also share every earlier commit (to the left of `*`), but `*` is the most interesting such commit.  We call this commit the *merge base* of `branchA` and `branchB`.

When you run:

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ git merge branchB
```

the `git merge` step sees that we are *on* `branchA` (due to the `git checkout` command), and that we are asking to merge the tip-most commit of `branchB`.  Git then locates this merge base commit, and runs *two* `git diff` commands.

Let's say the hash of commit `*` is `ba5e...`, and the tip commit on `branchA` is commit `1111...` with the tip commit of `branchB` being `2222...`.  The two `git diff` commands are then essentially:

```
$ git diff ba5e 1111
```

and:

```
$ git diff ba5e 2222
```

The first diff tells Git "what we did": what *we* changed from `*` to the tip of `branchA`.  The second diff tells Git "what they did": what *they* changed going from `*` to the tip of `branchB`.

A *merge conflict* occurs when some part of "what we did" changes the same line(s) of the same file(s) as some part of "what they did" changes, but the two changes are different.  For instance, if we both change `README.txt` to change the color of an apple, but *we* change it from purple to black, and they change it from purple to orange, Git doesn't know which one to take.

So, let's do just that:

```
mkdir mtest && cd mtest && git init
echo 'for testing' > README.txt
echo 'have a purple apple' >> README.txt
git add README.txt && git commit -m initial
```

This creates branch `master` with one file, `README.txt`.  Now let's create two separate branches forking from this one commit, and change the color of the apple in each branch:

```
git checkout -b branchA master
sed -i '' s/purple/black/ README.txt
git add README.txt && git commit -m black

git checkout -b branchB master
sed -i '' s/purple/orange/ README.txt
git add README.txt && git commit -m black
```

Now we simply merge one branch with the other.  We are currently on `branchB`, so we can `git merge branchA` now.  Once we resolve the conflict and commit, we'll have a merge on `branchB`.  Or, we can `git checkout branchA` first, then `git merge branchB`.  We will get the *same* conflict, but once we resolve it and commit, we'll have a merge on `branchA`.